# Using a controller variable in application html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm probably trying too hard for my first website but i wanted to make a dropdown on a (bootstrap) navbar to be flexible, and show the names of the saved work categories.

This is what i've tried to do in the application.html.erb file :

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% @workcategory.each do |workcategory| %>
    <li><%= workcategory.name%></li>
    <% end %>
```

Failed with error `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`on the`<% @workcategory.each do |workcategory| %>` line.

This is the workcategories controller :

```
class WorkcategoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_workcategory, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    def index
        @workcategories = Workcategory.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
    def new
        @workcategory = Workcategory.new
    end
    def create
        @workcategory = Workcategory.new(post_params)
        if @workcategory.save
            flash[:notice] = "Workcategory created"
            redirect_to(:action=>'index', :workcategory_id => @workcategory.id)
        else
            @workcategories = Workcategories.order()
            render('new')
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
        @workcategory.destroy
        redirect_to workcategory_path
    end
    private
    def find_workcategory
        @workcategory=Workcategory.find(params[:id])
    end
    def post_params
        params.require(:workcategory).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Any tips and help are welcome, even non-related to the initial question :) Thank you

Comment: In which action do you want worker category?

Comment: well that's the problem. there isn't any action, i want it in the application.html.erb. I've looked around for some other topics like these suggesting using a before_filter. but that didn't work out. So now i'm stuck ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it in all ur actions, it is wise to put it in your `application_controller.rb`.

```
before_filter :set_work_categories

def set_work_categoriers
    @w_categories =  Workcategory.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

This should work fine.

Also, a tip.

You can use `default_scope {order(created_at: :desc)}` in your model `WorkCategory.rb`

Then you can use this like,

```
def set_work_categoriers
  @w_categories =  Workcategory.all
end
```

I would recommend changing the variable name to @w_categories or else it will conflict with your @work_categories name in `index` action.

In your `application.html.erb` file, change

```
<% unless @w_categories.nil? %>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% @w_categories.each do |workcategory| %>
      <li><%= workcategory.name%></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<%end>
```

I guess this should do the trick

Comment: This gave me 'undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass'. I've removed that line and got back to nil class. etc ... i'm thinking i'm maybe not saving it right or something....

Comment: I added the change.Just as a confirmation, do you have data in `Workcategory` model?

Comment: hey yes thanks for the unless. I've tried it, and although it doesn't work like i want it. Now i/we know that the work category isn't saved correctly. When i go to rails console and check, i have 3 work categories but they just don't show ... and i've tried the before_filter and still doesn't. any ideas ?

Comment: @alexlug, try `better_errors` gem for dynamic debugging

Comment: ha in the end it was a mix between your answer and Rich's :) now it works, thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

If we talk about `index` action, then you just forgot to use appropriate variable:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <% @workcategories.each do |workcategory| %>
  <li><%= workcategory.name%></li>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

If you want to have this in all actions, then initialize `@workcategories` in `before_action`:

```
# your_controller.rb
before_action :initialize_work_categories
def initialize_work_categories
  @workcategories = Workcategory.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: this is giving me the same error. I actually tried 'workcategories' before and it wasn't working :) so the issue is somewhere else. thank you.

Comment: hey i've already tried this second option, the update. And this didn't work either. i'm getting the same error.

Comment: @alexlug, please update the answer with the exact code you tried (including this `before_action`)

Comment: In the end i went for this =>   before_action :work_categories
  private
  def work_categories
   @workcategory = Workcategory.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end. Now that i think about it you did post an alright version, but me being a total beginner i didn't know what was up and failed to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Layouts**

`application.html.erb` is a **layout**, meaning that it will be present regardless of whether you're using the `Workcategories` controller or not.

If you want to load a variable into the *layout*, irrespective of which controller is being invoked, you'll need to make sure the `@workcategory` variable is present.

To do this, you would generally put the `@workcategory` declaration into the `ApplicationController` (which most other controllers inherit from):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_categories

   private

   def set_categories
      @workcategory = ....
   end
end
```

This is the standard way to populate layout-side variables. It's not efficient and *only* works if your controllers inherit from the `Application` controller.

---

Some further pointers would include the following:

**1. Object orientation**

Ruby, and by virtue, Rails, is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

This means that everything you do should revolve around *objects*. This is why Rails has many helpers that seem to work "magically".

They're not magic at all - they just take the *objects* you pass them, and build pre-baked HTML to give you specific functionality.

A good example are the [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller
```

[image]

The reason this is important is that when you call actions / variables, you need to think of them as *objects*. This is difficult to do for newbies, but if you can get your head around it, it helps your coding massively.

--

**2. Controllers**

Following on from the above, you have to remember that your *controller* is really just a way to manipulate objects.

Thus, if you're calling `@workcategory`, you need to appreciate where the object is going to come from and how it's going to be populated.

Comment: thank you .. this was the missing piece, that before_action combined with Amit's code ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper method work_categories and use that. Either define it directly in application_helper - or if you don't want to use helpers you can put this code in your ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def work_categories
    Workcategory.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
  helper_method :work_categories

end
```

Then in your view:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <% work_categories.each do |workcategory| %>
    <li><%= workcategory.name%></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: hello. I've tried this and it threw : undefined method `helper_method' for main:Object

Comment: Did you add the code to apps/controllers/application_controller.rb ?

Comment: That's odd. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method

Comment: The method needs to be defined within the ApplicationController code. I've modified my answer to show this.